# Notation of Multiplying Combination Consecutive Integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

What is the most convenient notation for the following (keep it elementary if you can please.)

I have a given, finite set of consecutive integers, example:

$$ (7,6,5) $$

I want to sum the products of the elements of the ($size(set)-1$) combinations like this:

$$ S =(7\cdot 6)+(7\cdot 5)+(6\cdot5)$$

But more generally for a set of arbitrary size like:

$$(n,n-1,n-2,..., k+2,k+1,k)$$
$$S = \big[n\cdot (n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k+1) +\require{cancel}\cancel{k} \big]+\big[n\cdot (n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot\cancel{(k+1)}\cdot(k)\big]+\ldots+ \big[\cancel{n}\cdot (n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k+1) +{k} \big] $$

Therfore summing the products of all the combinations of the set with one (different) element removed each time.

Comment: Look like $\sum_\limits{i=k}^n \frac {n!}{(k-1)!i}$ should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly a notation, but how about this?

$$\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}\sum_{j=k}^n\frac 1j$$

Comment: Is there no formula for the 1/j sum?